# Jenkins fail to run maven clean deploy

Tags: maven, jenkins

Jenkins job fails to run the maven and there y, skipping the build step and directly going to post build actions.

1) JDK path is intact as other jobs successfully runs the build.
2) Using the Maven default settings /  Maven default global settings.
3) Not using mvn in the POM.xml / -U clean deploy

What might be the reason for the Jenkins to skip the maven build?

Comment: We need the error log, otherwise it is very difficult to help.

Comment: It doesn't give any error and it just skip the Build step

Comment: What does the log say about the skipping?

Comment: Does the agent on which it runs have the SDK installed?